# Convertir int a string para romper ciclo While

Tags: python

Estoy estudiando Python y tengo la siguiente duda a la que no pude encontrar respuesta.

Cree una función para que se ingresen números pares o impares a una lista, y quiero que se salga de la función al ingresar "fin". Quiero mantener los números como naturales para poder procesarlos.
Como puedo hacer para que al chequear que numero != "FIN" me lo considere como String y no me de error, pero que tanto al ingresarlo como cargarlo en el vector sea entero?

MUCHAS GRACIAS

```
def cargar(par, impar):
    numero = int(input("ingrese un numero:"))
    while numero.upper != "FIN":
        if numero % 2 == 0:
            par.append(numero)
        else:
            impar.append(numero)
        numero = int(input("ingrese un numero: "))

vecpar = []
vecimpar = []

cargar(vecpar, vecimpar)
```

Comment: primero verifica si `numero == "FIN"` y si no lo es haces la conversión `int(numero)`. En resumen no hagas la conversión al recibir el input, hazla dentro del `while`, `numero = int(numero)`

Answer (score 3):

La solución es hacer el ingreso como texto para compararlo con la palabra "FIN". En caso contrario, usar `int()` para transformar el ingreso a valor numérico:

```
def cargar(par, impar):
    entrada = input("ingrese un numero:")
    while entrada.upper() != "FIN":
        numero = int(entrada)
        if numero % 2 == 0:
            par.append(numero)
        else:
            impar.append(numero)
        entrada = input("ingrese un numero: ")

vecpar = []
vecimpar = []

cargar(vecpar, vecimpar)
```

produce:

```
ingrese un numero:1
ingrese un numero: 2
ingrese un numero: 3
ingrese un numero: fin

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Excelente, esta clarisimo. Muchisimas gracias!